# Question Regarding week relationships on views

Tags: schemacrawler

Can we create week relationships on views (or) there is any solution to create informative constraints against view instead of table for ER diagram creation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have created one .yml file with the data name: catalog
weak-associations:
- name: f_columnnme
referenced-table:
catalog: PUBLIC
schema: test
name: table1
referencing-table:
catalog: PUBLIC
schema: test
name: table3
column-references:
column2: column2
remarks:

- name: FK_columnname
referenced-table:
catalog: PUBLIC
schema: test
name: D_testtable
referencing-table:
catalog: PUBLIC
schema: test
name: table1
column-references:
column1: column1
remarks:

Comment: after that i am trying to read the yml file using below command schemacrawler --server=db2 --host=*** --database=*** --user=bluadmin --password=*** --schemas=*** --info-level=standard --command=brief --tables=".*\.table1.*||.*\.table2.*||.*\.table3.*" --only-matching --table-types=VIEW --weak-associations=TRUE --output-format=pdf --output-file=/tmp/Schema_ELIG_RULE_view1.pdf --attributes-file=/tmp/attribute.yml --log-level=CONFIG i am facing error like no such reference found in column level on view like this how i can overcome this

Comment: @SamineniKrishna Please put this information in the question itself, so it is readable